# Changing the environment variables in ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables

I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I want to set gfortran and c compilers as well as the OpenMPI library into the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variables.

I want to compile a code, and there is a instruction for that. The instruction says that the environment variables of libraries and compilers should be changed as below:

Make sure the compilers and libraries paths are set in the appropriate environment variables (PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH). Here are some examples which will need to be adapted for your setup:

On Ubuntu:

```
  export PATH=/usr/lib/openmpi/bin:${PATH}

  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Moreover, when I run the code, I face the following error:
"Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing: MPI_Fortran_WORKS)"

I do not know how to change the environmental variables for gfortran and other compilers.

Thanks in advance

Saeed

I reviewed all options in the websites but the issue has not been solved.

Comment: Hello. Several things are missing from your question that are needed to help you. What version of Ubuntu? What programming language do you want to use? This does not help @and other compilers@ you need to specify.

Comment: If you've installed openmpi from the Ubuntu repositories most build systems are smart enough to locate the components without modifying the environment

Comment: Thank you very much. I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I want to set gfortran and c++ compilers as well as the OpenMPI library into the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variables.

Comment: So how did you install the OpenMPI? If you installed `libopenmpi-dev` from the Ubuntu repo, then all the relevant compiler wrappers (`mpicc`, `mpic++`, `mpif90` etc.) should be in the default `/usr/bin`. The package also provides `.pc` files that build systems can use to locate headers and libraries ex. `pkg-config --cflags --libs mpi-fort`

Comment: Yes, I have installed libopenmpi-dev

Comment: I think it's going to be hard to help you without more details about the software and build commands that you are using. BTW is the `gfortran` package installed?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes. The `gfortran` has been installed